# jQuery validation not working with that form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I have been trying to validate a form with jquery validate plugin.As a newbie i am facing problem with that.Here is the code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#log-form").validate({
    errorElement: 'div',
    rules: {
      "username": {
        required: true,
        minlength: 5
      },
      "password": {
        required: true,
        minlength: 5
      }
    },
    messages: {
      username: {
        required: "Provide a username,sire",
        minlength: "Username with length 5 atleast,is required"
      },
      password: {
        required: "Provide a password,sire",
        minlength: "Minimum length of 5 is required for password,sire"
      }
    }
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      form.submit();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<form name="log-form" id="log-form" method="post" action="check_login.php">
  <label for="username">Username</label>
  <input type="text" class="" id="username" name="username">
  <br>
  <label for="password">Password</label>
  <input type="password" class="" id="password" name="password">
  <br>
  <button type="submit" name="sub-btn" class="sub-btn">Login</button>>
</form>
```

The validation is not working as i change field after typing in one neither on submiting the form.

Comment: There is a syntax error in your code, missing `,` after the `messages` property. Please check [How can I debug my JavaScript code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code)

Comment: you need to add <script type="text/javascript"></script> in that javascript

Comment: @JosuaMarcelChrisano actually i was using script tag,but didn't added that here,thanks BTW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @unidentified: There is a syntax error in your code, missing , after the messages property. Please check [How can I debug my JavaScript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#log-form").validate({
    errorElement: 'div',
    rules: {
      "username": {
        required: true,
        minlength: 5
      },
      "password": {
        required: true,
        minlength: 5
      }
    },
    messages: {
      username: {
        required: "Provide a username,sire",
        minlength: "Username with length 5 atleast,is required"
      },
      password: {
        required: "Provide a password,sire",
        minlength: "Minimum length of 5 is required for password,sire"
      }
    },                // syntax error, comma was missing here
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      form.submit();
    }
  });
});
```